# Why are some NuGet packages named with nuget-bot?

Tags: nuget

I went to add a NuGet package for Microsoft.TeamFoundationTracking.Client and in the list of available packages I have the options:

Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client

and

**nuget-bot**.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client

The one with nuget-bot has a higher version number than the one without it. I don't ever recall seeing packages with the nuget-bot in the name. I assume there is some convention or format that this refers to.

Thanks for any explanation of what this means.

Comment: You might want to read https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2015/08/10/nuget-packages-for-tfs-and-visual-studio-online-net-client-object-model/ , Also, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34830333/10245

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the nuget-bot packages, but if you are looking for official Microsoft binaries, you will want to look for those where the Owner is set to Microsoft (not just the author).  The package you seek is most likely: Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient