# How to solve Failed to add reference to 'Microsoft.WITDataStore'?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I got empty `Class library` project and want to install following NuGet as dependency:

`nuget-bot.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader.12.0.31101`

Installation fails with error:

> Failed to add reference to 'Microsoft.WITDataStore'.

Other nugets, e.g. `Entity Framework` or `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` I was able to install.

**My Configuration**

- Windows 7 Enterprise
- Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
- NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32128581/968011
I asked Microsoft a similar question this summer.

Comment: Related post - [Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll' (TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31031817/465053)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like this is a mistake in the configuration of [the NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/nuget-bot.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader/).

`Microsoft.WITDataStore.dll` is an unmanaged library that cannot be directly referenced by a .NET project, which is why the package installation fails.

The `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTrackingClient.DataStoreLoader.dll` is a .NET wrapper library allowing access to the unmanaged code in  `Microsoft.WITDataStore.dll`.  What *should* be happening is that the package should add the .NET library (`DataStoreLoader.dll`) as an assembly reference and add the unmanaged library (`WITDataStore.dll`) as a content-item configured to be copied into the `bin\` directory on build.  Instead, it's attempting to add them both as assembly references, which fails and is rolled back by NuGet.

I've used NuGet's "Contact Owner" feature to attempt to notify the publisher at Microsoft of the package's misconfiguration, but since it's been published by "nuget-bot", I don't know if that will accomplish anything.  I'll update this answer if the package is updated to resolve the issue.
The workaround I'm currently using is to:

1. [manually download](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/nuget-bot.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader/12.0.31101) the package, unzip it, and copy the unzipped folder into my solution's `packages\` directory.
2. Add a reference in my project to the copy of `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTrackingClient.DataStoreLoader.dll` in the unzipped package.
3. Add the file `WITDataStore.dll` as an Existing File to my project, and mark it as "Copy Always" under "Properties".  ("Copy if newer" will also work just fine)
4. Add the line `<package id="nuget-bot.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader" version="12.0.31101" targetFramework="net452" />` to the `packages.config` file for my project.

This results in NuGet having a record of the package being installed, the `DataStoreLoader.dll` being referenced, and the `WITDataStore.dll` being copied into your `bin\` folder whenever you build, so it can be used by wrapper library.

Comment: 1 a. After manually downloading the file from the https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/nuget-bot.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader/12.0.31101, make sure to change the file extension nuget-bot.microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.datastoreloader.12.0.31101.nupkg to nuget-bot.microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.datastoreloader.12.0.31101.nupkg.rar. Then you may use any file compression software to extract the content of the downloaded file. I used WinRar for my case, so...

Answer (score 0):

Please use the official NuGet packages. I've written this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2015/08/10/nuget-packages-for-tfs-and-visual-studio-online-net-client-object-model/) as a guide. I still hope to get the non-official packages taken down.

Comment: Any idea who this mysterious nuget-bot is? I haven't got to the bottom of it

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this error by simply copied **Microsoft.WITDataStore.dll** in to Microsoft Team Foundation packages folder. You can copy this dll after downloading this package manually.

```
packages\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.11.0.0.0\lib\net20
```

Hope this helps you